# How to refresh Maya cmds.gridLayout?

Tags: python, refresh, maya

Maya cmds: I have a basic grid and I want to remove an item, but the grid doesn't update. So the removed item keeps taking up space. How can I make the gridLayout refresh or re-align its items?

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

def change(*args):
    cmds.iconTextCheckBox('two', edit=True, visible=False)

window = cmds.window()
cmds.gridLayout()

cmds.iconTextCheckBox('one', style='textOnly', label='item')
cmds.iconTextCheckBox('two', style='textOnly', label='item')
cmds.iconTextCheckBox('three', style='textOnly', label='item')

cmds.button(label='GO', command=change)
cmds.showWindow(window)
```

Comment: if I remember well, you are not removing the item, you re just making it invisible. In theory you would have to remove the widget/item from the layout by using QT method removeWidget or removeItem, you can also delete the widget or use a model method to populate it. Here with maya.cmds you might have to recreate your grid each time

Comment: Yeah recreating the grid each time is the only thing that is working at the moment. But I have over 1500 items in the list. So even if you just want to remove 10, you need to delete and recreate the grid. Which is obviously horrible. So I was hoping someone could give me a better solution :) But thanks for your input as well!

Answer (score 1):

Executing your code you don't delete the second element, you're just turning its visibility off.

[image]

To check this statement, execute the following line of code and you'll turn a visibility on:

```
cmds.iconTextCheckBox('two', edit=True, visible=True)
```

[image]

## Solution

You need to use QT's [QGridLayout()](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgridlayout.html#QGridLayout-1) class (not Maya's cmds).
To remove a widget from a layout, call `removeWidget()` method.

Comment: So are you saying I can't use `cmds.gridLayout()`? Because it doesn't seem like there is anything like `cmds.gridLayout().removeWidget()`

Comment: Seems so. I haven't found any method for regular cmds `widget`. But I could be wrong.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the answer! I'll upvote it, but unfortunately it doesn't really answer my question. It gives a good workaround though. THANK YOU!

Comment: I'm still trying to solve this problem using regular `cmds` approach)